# Additional info about employer

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think it's greate if I can add website link and some short additional info about employer.

Example:

> Example Corp. was founded in 2002 as a
>   branch of BigExample, that belong in
>   the Example Group. The residence is in
>   Paris, the France.
>
> The main activity is development
>   information system for Universities.

Comment: Is the CV about you or about the businesses you've worked for/at?

Answer (score 1):

I did so, but only minimally, by adding some information to the responsibilities field on each experience. As you can use Markdown in these fields, there is no problem adding links to the company website.

There are cases were providing information about the company will add to your CV, and there are countries were this is pretty common.